# Unity: Apply shader to object to curve its texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, shader

I'm making a endless runner game in Unity, and I want to add a curved shader to it like in this tutorial https://youtu.be/6_e_GoWlZOo

But when I add that material to a object it replaces the old one. And when I add it as second one in the Mesh Renderer it doesn't affect the first one. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-kP4A0Xh3P9xVjrwjTiTPlh_WcHnBA1d

This is the shader code:

```
Shader "PPP/BendWorld"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Curvature("Curvature", Float) = 0.001
    }
        SubShader
        {
            Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
            LOD 200

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert addshadow
            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
            uniform float _Curvature;

            struct Input 
            {
                float uv_MainTex;
            };

            void vert(inout appdata_full v) 
            {
                float4 worldSpace = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
                worldSpace.xyz -= _WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz;
                worldSpace = float4(0.0f, (worldSpace.x * worldSpace.x) * -_Curvature, 0.0f, 0.0f);

                v.vertex += mul(unity_WorldToObject, worldSpace);
            }

            void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) 
            {
                half4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
                o.Albedo = c.rgb;
                o.Alpha = c.a;
            }

            ENDCG
    }
            Fallback "Mobile/Diffuse"
}
```

I want to curve the object and have a texture on it, is there any way to do this?

Comment: The shader has it's own texture property. Therefore you should add this shader along with your desired texture to the object - making a new material. Adding two materials/shaders to the object won't work, as you noticed. (Sorry if I misunderstood the question.)

Comment: So should I create new shader material for each object with its texture?
I've already tried this, but that texture is broken
This is with normal texture
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mipTfiobyB7PDTT6qiw9udX9HgiA2zZ9
And this is with that shader with the same texture 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uMafa5qbh-g4gFh6E1SHsJ3-McJjJG8x

Comment: Is that a water shader with moving water? If so, you're in for a bit of work. Then you must modify that shader to work with curvature. You can't just add another shader and expect them to work together.

Comment: No its just a picture

Comment: The texture is broken because you have defined your uv_MainTex as a float instead of a float2. UV coordinates are two-dimensional.

Comment: @KalleHalvarsson can you post this as an answer instead of comment, so it can be accepted? OP confirmed to me it worked (he's a student in my group where he's working on this project).

Comment: @KalleHalvarsson thank you so much, it works

Comment: @Teo.sk No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the texture issue: The texture looks broken because you have defined your uv_MainTex as a float instead of a float2. UV coordinates are two-dimensional - if you define it as a scalar, it will only use the U axis of the UVs.